# Configure alertmanager alerting in prometheus helm chart values.yaml

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to connect prometheus to alertmanager and I'm facing a problem with configuring alertmanager alerting endpoints in values.yaml helm chart. 
I tried it before with docker-compose and it worked but it's different with helm charts.

I downloaded the official helm chart for prometheus that includes alertmanager
I configured the services and the targets to scrape but I can't find where to specify alertmanager to prometheus to try to forward the alerts and send it by slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest configuration is set the configMapOverride: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/da8b2fa27f81a4a4d44e1ac320f9081a5948224e/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L68

After configuring this, you must create a configMap with all configuration like a usually alertmanager: 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/prometheus/alertmanager-configmap.yaml

Comment: second link is broken, it would be helpful if maybe some code or a snipped was pasted in to this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you already moved to `kube-prometheus-stack`, you could try the following steps:

1. create a values.yaml

   ```sh
   # values.yaml
   alertmanager:
     config:
       global:
         resolve_timeout: 5m
         # The API URL to use for Slack notifications.
         [ slack_api_url: <secret> ]
         [ slack_api_url_file: <filepath> ]
   ```
2. `apply` or `upgrade` your release

   ```sh
   helm install|upgrade [RELEASE] prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f values.yaml
   ```

REF:

- https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#alertmanager-configuration
- https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L150-L170
- https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#configuration-file